# How can I animate two images enter and exit animation at the same time

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I am trying to make images sliding in and out for my login page.

I am using React  & framer-motion

I use  from framer-motion and I believe I set up everything correctly.

The initial prop for the motion.img is y: -1000
The animate prop is y: 0
the exit prop is y: 1000

For some reason, when the images switch, I only get the exit animation.
Below is codesandbox link.

How can i make it so when the image switches, the next image pushes down the previous one?

https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-paper-vquog?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

I asked for help on the github of framer-motion.
Make the images absolute and then it works correctly.
Full explanation [here](https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/1359)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).